# select entities multiselect attribute which stored as comma separated ints in varchar table

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, multiselect

Some product attribute is multiselect and stored as:

`954,955,956,957,958,959` in database

How to select products with 954 option id ?

`like` seems to be not accurate, string should be spitted by comma, and then compared to condition

I found some `SUBSTRING_INDEX` solutions but not sure its best way, how magento (magento2) itself handles it?

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` will work